# Unable to resize a column in Google Docs - the column options disabled

Tags: google-docs

I'm facing an issue with resizing the columns of my tables in Google Docs: neither of options seem to work (dragging a border is unavailable, dragging the ruler is unavailable, Format -> Columns is greyed out and Column Width in Table Properties is greyed out too. I couldn't find any settings responsible for that. How can resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add more details. Is this a document that you created from scratch or it is result of converting a document created in other app to Google Docs? How many columns has your document? Does it has a paragraph above and below of the table? Does the table fits one page or it extend across multiple pages?

Answer (score 3):

If you are in "Suggesting" mode you will be unable to edit column width. Switch to editing and you should be able to drag column lines around again or edit in Table Properties again.

Answer (score 0):

Click in the header of the column you need to adjust, then select **Format** from the menu bar, select **Table**, then select **Table Properties**.  This will give you all the adjustments you need for your columns. :-)